# tmux, I can set 'pane-border-format' but i can't get 'pane-border-format', so to that end, how to get pane options?

Tags: tmux

I can do this:

```
tmux set-option -g 'pane-border-format'
```

but when I do this:

```
tmux show-options -gv 'pane-border-format'
```

I just get the error:

```
unkown-option: pane-border-format
```

what gives? Why can I set it but not get it like you can with `status-left` or `status-right`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pane options are apart of the window global options, thus it's best to use:

```
tmux showw -gv "pane-border-format"
```

Comment: tmux show -gw "pane-border-format"